# MongoDB: Why $literal required ? And where it can be used?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have gone through MongoDB **$literal** in **Aggregation** framework, but I don't understand where it could be used ? more importantly, why it is required ?

> Example from official MongoDB documentation,

```
db.records.aggregate( [
   { $project: { costsOneDollar: { $eq: [ "$price", { $literal: "$1" } ] } } }
])
```

Instead of the above example using $literal, why can't I use as below ?

```
db.records.aggregate( [
   { $project: { costsOneDollar: { $eq: [ "$price", "$1" ] } } }
] )
```

Also provide some other example which shows the best(or effective) usage of **$literal**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your basic case I think the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#treat-as-a-literal) is fairly self explanatory:

> *In expression, the dollar sign $ evaluates to a field path; i.e. provides access to the field. For example, the $eq expression $eq: [ "$price", "$1" ] performs an equality check between the value in the field named price and the value in the field named 1 in the document.*

So since `$` is reserved for evaluation of field path values within the document, then this would be considered to acutally be looking for a "field" named `1` within the document. So the actual comparsion would likely be between the field named "price" and since there is no field named "1" then this would be treated as `null` and therefore `false` for every document.

On the other hand where the field "price" actually has a value equal to `"$1"`, then the usage of `$literal` allows that "value" ( and not the field path reference ) to be considered. Hence "literal".

The operator has actually been around for some time ( since MongoDB 2.2 actually ) but under the guise of `$const`, which though not doucmented is still the basic operator, and `$literal` is really just an "alias" for that.

The usage mainly is and always has been to use where an [expression](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions) is required to have some "specific value" as instructed within the pipeline. Take this simple statement:

```js
{ "$project": { "myField": "one" } }
```

So for any number of reasons you might want to do that, and basically return a "literal" value in such a statement. But if you tried, it would result in a error as it essentially does not resolve to either a "field path" or a `boolean` condition for field selection, as is required here. So if you instead use:

```js
{ "$project": { "myField": { "$literal": "one" } } }
```

Then you have "myField" with a value of "one" just like you asked for.

Other usages are more historic, such as:

```js
{ "$project": { "array": { "$literal": ["A","B","C" ] } } },
{ "$unwind": "$array" },
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "trans": { "$push": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$array", "A" ] },
            "$fieldA",
            { "$cond": [ 
                { "$eq": [ "$array", "B" ] },
                "$fieldB",
                "$fieldC"
            ]}
        ]
    }}
}}
```

Which might more modernly be replaced with something like:

```js
{ "$project": {
    "trans": {
        "$map": {
            "input": ["A","B","C"],
            "as": "el",
            "in": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$$el", "A" ] },
                    "$fieldA",
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$$el", "B" ] },
                        "$fieldB",
                        "$fieldC"
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

As a construct to move selected fields into an array based on position, with the difference being that as "array" and a field assignment the `$literal` is necessary, but as the "input" argument the plain array notation is just fine.

So the general cases are:

1. Where something reserved such as `$` is needed as the value to match
2. Where there is a specific value to inject as a field assignment, and not as an argument to another operator expression.

Answer (score 1):

The `$1` example you give would try and compare the `price` field with the `1` field. By specifying the `$literal` operator, you're telling MongoDB that it is the exact string `"$1"`. The same might be true if you wanted to use a MongoDB function name as a field name in your code, or even using a query snippet as a field value.